# I want a regex code that accepts only a list of characters that are seperated by a comma or a space

Tags: regex

So my problem is that i have a text field and i want the user to type a list of days only and to not accept any other word for example :

```
    monday tuesday saturday 
    or monday,tuesday,saturday
```

this is what i wrote

```
    "\b(monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday|\b"
```

but this didn't work i don't know why i'm a regex beginner and i need some help, thank you guys.

Comment: you can test online, for example regex101.com

Comment: Is this some type of learning project? Users (myself included) wouldn't normally bother typing out full names of a day let alone a list of them.

Comment: which regex flavor are you using? please mention it.

Answer (score 2):

```
^((monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday)[, ])*(monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday)$
```

The `^` will *anchor* the pattern to match the start of the value, and the `$` anchors at the end of the value. The combination of those two means the pattern will only match if the entire value matches. Without the anchors, the pattern would match anything which contains the pattern.

The pattern is saying that it must be zero or more dayname-followed-by-space-or-comma, followed by a dayname.

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern the last pipe `|` of the alternation should be a closing parenthesis to close the group and you are not taking a comma or a space into account.

```
\b(monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday|\b
                                                           ^
```

If you are not referring to the capturing groups in your code or tool, you could make them non capturing using `(?:` instead of `(`

You might update your pattern to use anchors `^` and `$` to assert the start and the end of the string. Then match 1 day and repeat 0+ times matching another day prededing with a comma or a space.

```
^(?:mon|tues|wednes|thurs|fri|satur|sun)day(?:[, ](?:mon|tues|wednes|thurs|fri|satur|sun)day)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O7PVdg/1)

If you want to allow only the specified formats and for example not `monday tuesday,saturday` using a space AND a comma you could capture the space or comma the first time and then make use of a backreference using `\1`:

```
^(?:mon|tues|wednes|thurs|fri|satur|sun)day(?:([, ])(?:mon|tues|wednes|thurs|fri|satur|sun)day)?(?:\1(?:mon|tues|wednes|thurs|fri|satur|sun)day)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O7PVdg/2/)